# apple sign in for existing accounts

Tags: ios13, apple-sign-in

I would like to understand how we apply apples sign in to a service where the user already has an existing account .  I can see Apple Sign in provides us with 2 successful reponses,

usercredentials for a new sign in.

passwordcredential for an existing sign in.

If I have an existing app service and the user already has an email/password account , maybe token based authentication for example,  how do I go about associating my new or existing Apple ID credential with that existing account ?  or is that not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is if the user choose to hide email then you `cannot link existing account`. But if user is sharing his real email id and you already have that email id in your database, then ***`you have to have logic where account is dependent on the email id`***.

so all the corresponding app-User related data/task should be carried out int that way.

The other way is to have email id and user - first name, last name combination.
As you only get email, user -first name and last name from the data received by apple apart from unique token.